# При установке Brackets в ubuntu выдает ошибку

Tags: ubuntu, brackets

в терминале пишу:

```
sudo dpkg -i Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета brackets.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 212570 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb …
Распаковывается brackets (1.14.1-17752) …
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет brackets:
 brackets зависит от gconf-service, однако:
  Пакет gconf-service не установлен.
 brackets зависит от libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1), однако:
  Пакет libgconf-2-4 не установлен.
 brackets зависит от libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), однако:
  Пакет libpango1.0-0 не установлен.
 brackets зависит от libcurl3, однако:
  Пакет libcurl3 не установлен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета brackets (--install):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Обрабатываются триггеры для hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 brackets
```

Comment: даже не по-английски, а по-русски написано, какие необходимые пакеты не установлены.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install gconf-service libgconf-2-4 libpango1.0-0 libcurl3 && sudo dpkg -i Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb`